# how to pass a object as callback parameter in Lua

Tags: lua

Define a View and `ViewGroup` class, View's `onDraw` method which can be customized,  Traverse all View object in ViewGroup, execute its `onDraw` method,  and pass the Canvas obj to the `onDraw` method.

Can not call Canvas's methods in View's onDraw and cannot use `self` to call properties in View, Can guarantee Canvas obj is correct.
The example code is follows:

```
ViewGroup = {    
  childcount = 0,
  childs = {} -- view object list
}

function ViewGroup:onDraw(canvas)
    for i=1,self.childcount do
          local childView = self.childs[i]
          childView:onDraw(canvas)
    end
end


View = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    width = 0,
    height = 0,
    onDraw = nil
}

function View:new()
    local o = {
        onDraw = nil
    }
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

button1 = View:new()
button1.onDraw = function(canvas)
   -- the problem is here, can not call Canvas's method and can not call self.width
    canvas:save()
    canvas:fillRect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
    canvas:restore()
end
```

Error prompt:

```
attempt to call a nil value (method 'save')
attempt to index a nil value (global 'self')
```

Comment: Try `button1.onDraw = function(self, canvas)`

Comment: Quite correct, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring the callback with the dot (`.`) syntax:

```
button1.onDraw = function(canvas)
```

But you're calling it with a colon (`:`):

```
childView:onDraw(canvas)
```

The 2nd call convention means that the first passed parameter is going to be `self`, or, in your specific case, it's equivalent to:

```
childView.onDraw(childView, canvas)
```

---

To fix this, either change the button's `onDraw` to use `:`:

```
function button1:onDraw(canvas)
```

Or add the `self` parameter by hand, like Egor suggested:

```
button1.onDraw = function(self, canvas)
```

Comment: `button1:onDraw = function(canvas)` is a syntax error in Lua

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff oh damn, you're right. The syntax sugar works differently.

Comment: I add the `self ` parameter by hand, the problem has been solved. Thank you very much.